# can discarded things be picked?

Tags: sharia

What does islam say about discarded objects? can discarded things be picked?not lost but thrown away things e.g: you see some one throwing something in the bin, but it is reusable? should we let it go to waste? or use it?..

Answer (score 2):

If you have the permission of the owner or the department that discarded the object, then yes, go ahead and pick it and use it.

Electronic waste can be usable. Lets take discarded printers. These printers may look like a massive trash, but they contain very expensive parts including motor and moving parts. These are definitely usable.

One person may dislike the circuit while the other may be desperately needing that specific electronic component in that circuit.

This does not mean that one should look in places where he is not supposed to look. The privacy is to be respected in every case. Moreover, some discarded objects may be discarded for a reason. Be careful of objects that can cause damage to life.

And please be very careful and always make sure that picking discarded objects and stealing are entirely different things.